# Azure Application Gateway pointing to Azure CDN?

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-cdn

Has anyone experience with pointing an Application Gateway to an Azure CDN? We can add internal and public services to our App Gateway but as soon as we point to an Azure CDN, then problems starts to arise.
Here is what we are seeing:

- When adding a health probe pointing to the CDN it says everything is fine and it got a 200 reply.
- When using the Connection Troubleshoot tool and pointing it to the CDN, it says it is reachable.
- However, when checking the Backend Health, it says

> The backend health status could not be retrieved. This happens when an
> NSG/UDR/Firewall on the application gateway subnet is blocking traffic
> on ports 65503-65534 in case of v1 SKU, and ports 65200-65535 in case
> of the v2 SKU or if the FQDN configured in the backend pool could not
> be resolved to an IP address. To learn more visit -
> https://aka.ms/UnknownBackendHealth.

For one the backend health is not "unknown" but "unhealthy". And the tips there are not really useful. We don't have a blocking firewall and there are no NSGs.

And to make it even more confusing, it actually appears that the endpoint is functioning when accessing the App Gateway listener. But it is a bit sporadic and sometimes it doesn't work.

Any suggestion on how to debug this, as the tools available seems to indicate everything is fine until it is configured and the Backend Health says it is not?

***Update:***

It does in fact work if we use an IP from the CDN directly. Could indicate DNS issue however our DNS log does show that the App Gateway resolves the DNS.

Comment: What is the usecase of having Azure CDN as a backend of Application Gateway?
CDN is global service and Application Gateway is regional service.

Comment: Yes we are indeed aware of this and this is only temporary for a cloud migration project. Long term architecture will be different. Alternatively we have to go directly to the Azure Storage Account but then we misses out on the compression features of the CDN.

Comment: If you could share more details I would provide solution that is easier to implement out of box

Comment: Thanks, but we've already committed to a plan and why I agree, you wouldn't normally do this there is seemingly no reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: The use case would be to have a fixed IP address for accessing the content. Some of our corporate customers require fixed ip addresses, so they can whitelist it in their firewall and have more control.

Comment: Did you ever solve it by pointing to the CDN domain name?

Comment: @Paul0515 - No after being in touch with Microsoft support and they confirmed this was not an intended use-case (for obvious reasons as mentioned earlier), we decided to get rid of the CDN all-together as it was only ment to be part of a temporary architecture. Be aware that "Application Gateway resolves the DNS entries for the backend pool at time of startup and doesn't update them dynamically while running."